# Access 2010 - Providing the FE to Users

Tags: microsoft-access-2010, frontend

I have an Access database I split into backend and front end.  I want to share the Front End with users; however, I don't want them to have all the queries I use (not useful to them).  Can I hide my queries from them? Or will I need to save the Front End four different ways, one for each of my users?

Answer (score 0):

The front end is a separate database file that links to your back-end database tables.

Create a front-end with the items you want users to have access to and save it. There is no reason to create a file for each user. They can each have a copy of the same FE file.

What I did was copy the FE file I already had and stripped out all the objects I didn't want the users to have access to, removed menu selections and saved the file.

On a side note, you can also create a unique FE file for yourself with different content. I have done this with several databases in order for various user levels to have different FE files so they can only access what they need. My files as all the objects, where another has only a few forms the users needs to input data.